# File tree disappearing after opening a SAS table on SAS Enterprise Guide 8.1

Tags: sas

Switched recently from SAS EG 7 to SAS EG 8.1.

There is an annoying behavior now when using SAS EG 8.1: when I am opening a SAS table through the Servers panel, the file tree disappear (after opening the table), and if I want to look again at that table I would need to go through the whole file tree again.

When using SAS EG 7 there was never this behavior and I could just open a SAS table without the file tree to disappear and thus having to search again through the file tree.

I have spent some time looking at the options but I could not find something related to this.

Does anybody has a solution to this ?

Comment: This is a bug in EG 8.1. If you update to EG 8.2 or 8.3 this behavior goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stu Sztukowski pointed out, I updated from 8.1 to 8.2 and this behavior disappeared!